# Sending email works in localhost but not in hosted website(GoDaddy)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hosting, filepath, email-attachments

I've been working on a website using ASP.NET MVC in this website you can directly send an email to a specific email address. It's working properly, the email is sending without a problem. Not until I hosted it. I keep getting this error:

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions 65.55.176.126:587
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was
>   made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
>   65.55.176.126:587
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I don't know why it's working on localhost but not in hosted website. Someone please help me. I'm a newbie. Thank you in advance. Here's my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmailFormModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            List<string> paths = new List<string>();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    paths.Add(path);
                }
            }

                var message = new MailMessage();
                foreach (var path in paths)
                {
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
                    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    using (var stream = fileInfo.OpenRead())
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    }
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    string fileName = fileInfo.Name;
                    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, fileName));
                }

                //Rest of business logic here
                string EncodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];
                bool IsCaptchaValid = (ReCaptcha.Validate(EncodedResponse) == "True" ? true : false);
                if (IsCaptchaValid)
                {

                    var body = "<p><b>Email From:</b> {0} ({1})</p><p><b>Subject:</b> {2} </p><p><b>Message:</b></p><p>{3}</p><p><b>Software Description:</b></p><p>{4}</p>";
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(""));  // replace with valid value 
                    message.From = new MailAddress("");  // replace with valid value
                    message.Subject = "(Inquire for SELLING)";
                    message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.FromSubject, model.Message, model.Desc);
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        var credential = new NetworkCredential
                        {
                            UserName = "",  // replace with valid value
                            Password = ""  // replace with valid value
                        };
                        smtp.Credentials = credential;
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        smtp.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            //delete attached files
                            foreach (var path in paths)
                                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                        };
                        await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                        ViewBag.Message = "Your message has been sent!";

                        ModelState.Clear();
                        return View("Index");
                    }
                } else

                {
                    TempData["recaptcha"] = "Please verify that you are not a robot!";
                }

            } return View(model);

        }
```

Comment: You have this in a comment `// replace with valid value`. Have you actually replaced those with valid values?

Comment: @Andrew Yes Sir, I've put a valid value in it.

Comment: Please can you add the ***text*** of the error message that you receive rather than a screenshot. It's the most important piece of evidence in your question, and it's hidden in an image. Anyone else who hits this problem won't find this question.

Comment: @spender I just edit my question Sir.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the port you are using. You need to use a different SMTP library (instead of StmpClient) if your port is above 465 according to msdn.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I've change my port. And there's no more error Sir. But when I try to send it, it just keeps on "connecting", and not sending at all. What maybe the cause of it? Thank you.

Comment: It will need to be whatever port your smtp mail server allows. If they only allow the one given in your question, it might be the case that you need to keep the same port and change the code completely